# Start-Process : The system cannot find the file specified from TeamCity Build step but works fine locally

Tags: powershell, teamcity, pact, pact-broker, pact-net

i am trying to run Pact broker can i deploy tool with paramaters which is working fine locally but when i add the build step in TeamCity it is throwing below error

> Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The
>   system cannot   find the file specified.
>   [image]

when i run the same powershell script locally, it is working fine .

**powershell script:**
[image]

**CanIDeploy.bat  code is** 
[image]

Note: the reason i am calling pact-broker.bat from power shell script is, unable to run bat file from Teamcity , that is the reason created powershell script which internally calls pact broker bat file.
any help is appreciated

Comment: The error suggests that the file isn't present, which seems to be the issue - can you please show us conclusive evidence that the file indeed isn't present in the location specified?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use relative path, but what about the working directory? I see a different path in the error message vs what you show where the file is.